# For an array of numbers, return the number of times a certain number appears

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having issues with general cases, but have managed to get the edge cases done.
Here is what I have so far (fyi it is an intro to comp class so it is very basic stuff):

```
export let count = (a: number[], b: number): number => {

    let actually = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] === b) {
                return actually++;
            }
            if (a[i] !== b) {
                return actually;
            }
            }
        return actually;
    };
```

Outputs:

```
general cases:
FAIL: count([10, 20], 20)
string
-- Expected: 1
string
-- Actually: 0
string
FAIL: count([20, 20], 20)
string
-- Expected: 2
string
-- Actually: 0
string

edge cases:
PASS: count([], 20)
string
PASS: count([10, 30], 20)
```

Comment: You have `return actually++;` in the loop twice, but you don't want to be returning the value of `actually` until the end of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `return`, you end the function right there. So basically, your function as is only looks at the very first number, and returns 1 if it matches and returns 0 if it does not.

If you want to count the number of times you see the number in the entire list, you should increment `actually`, but not `return`.

Then, after you are done iterating through every element in the array, you can return `actually`, which should have the final count.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the exact problem (i'm still new to all of this), appreciate the quick reply jj172.

Comment: no prob! Feel free to ask me if you have any other basic questions, I can help answer :)

Comment: I'm also new to stack overflow, is there a way to chat or message? @jj172

Comment: @deem dont think so, actually... hm, maybe you'll just have to post more questions on here and hope that someone else more knowledgeable than me will see :P